# How to get the JSON data in Class in .NET , C#

Tags: c#, json, twitter

I want to send the data from class  Product.cs in Twitter by using twitterizer. I have done to send the string by twitterizer method and testing is correct. I have

http://cncpts.com/products.json

Which contains the json data I have produced the classes from JSON2CSharp. But i want to get the data from this json http://cncpts.com/products.json and want to put all the data in database.

Please tell me what is the way to link the classes with json. Below are the classes which i want to link with json data.

```
public class Product
{
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public string body_html { get; set; }
    public string published_at { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string vendor { get; set; }
    public string product_type { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> variants { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public List<Option> options { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Newtonsoft's JSON.NET Library for deserialization and get JSON String with WebClient, You can install JSON.NET from NuGet. Firstly you should create a model for your JSON like this :

```
class ProductsJsonModel
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

And then fetch your JSON String from URL and Deserialize this String to Class

```
using(var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()){
    var jsonString = webClient.DownloadString("http://cncpts.com/products.json");
    ProductsJsonModel Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductsJsonModel>(jsonString);
    List<Product> ProductsFromUrl = Data.products; // All of your products are here.
}
```

Comment: Dear Can you please tell me i am new in webform i want to show the ProductsFormUrl in .aspx . How can i show it   ? I place this code in TwitterStrap.aspx.cs and i want to show the data of list in TwitterStrap.aspx.. Thanks for your first answer